# Passing an array of char as a referenced pointer

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers

I'm trying to pass an `array[0..512] of char` as a referenced pointer to another function. However I don't understand how Delphi handles pointers.

In my button click code, I have this;

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sect_size: integer;
  sector : array[0..512] of char;
  hand : THandle;
  ret: integer;
begin

  hand := open_disk('system.img', sect_size);

  ret := read_disk(hand, @sector, 0, 1, sect_size);
end;
```

Then, for the `read_disk` function, I have this code;

```
function read_disk(hnd: THandle; var ptr:pointer; sector: int64; nsects, sectorsize: integer): DWORD;
var
  offset: int64;
  lw: DWORD;
  hgh: cardinal;
  len, rd: DWORD;
  ret: boolean;
  sc : array[0..512] of char;
begin
  offset := sector * sectorsize;

  lw := offset and $0FFFFFFFF;
  hgh := (offset SHR 32) and $0FFFFFFFF;

  lw := SetFilePointer(hnd, lw, @hgh, FILE_BEGIN);

  len := nsects * sectorsize;

  ret := ReadFile(hnd, ptr, len, rd, NIL);

  Result := rd;

end;
```

I am trying to pass the `sector` variable from the button click to the `read_disk` function, however Delphi throws a wobble and says; `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(245): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical`.

This error is on the `@sector` part on the line `ret := read_disk(hand, @sector, 0, 1, sect_size);`

Thanks

EDIT:
Working code now looks like;

```
function read_disk(hnd: THandle; ptr:pointer; sector: int64; nsects, sectorsize: integer): Cardinal;
var
  offset: int64;
  lw: DWORD;
  hgh: cardinal;
  len, rd: Cardinal;
  ret: boolean;
begin
  offset := sector * sectorsize;

  lw := offset and $0FFFFFFFF;
  hgh := (offset SHR 32) and $0FFFFFFFF;

  lw := SetFilePointer(hnd, lw, @hgh, FILE_BEGIN);

  len := nsects * sectorsize;

  ret := ReadFile(hnd, ptr^, len, Result, NIL);

end;
```

`ret := read_disk(hand, @sector, 0, 1, sect_size);`

Comment: You do realise that your arrays have 513 elements right?

Comment: Don't edit your question to post the solution. Write an answer instead - it's even encouraged here; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you have strict pointer checking enabled.

The cleaner, more Pascal'ish way to do what you want is something like

```
type
  TMyBuffer = array[0..512] of char;

function read_disk(hnd: THandle; var Buffer: TMyByffer; 
  sector: int64; nsects, sectorsize: integer): DWORD;
var
...
```

and then

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sect_size: integer;
  sector : TMyBuffer;
  hand : THandle;
  ret: integer;
begin

  hand := open_disk('system.img', sect_size);

  ret := read_disk(hand, sector, 0, 1, sect_size);
end;
```

Also, if you wanted to stay with using an opaque `pointer` type then `var` becomes redundant because you then pass a pointer to a pointer.

Oh, and then you probably meant `array[0..511] of char`, not 0..512 (nit).

Comment: If I remove the `var` deceleration, and then pass `@sector`, there is no error, but the program crashes after the `ReadFile` line. There are no errors, just `The program has stopped working`.

Comment: Apologies, just looked at it again. The code actually crashes when the `Result` is set from the function. I amended the array, it is now only 512 bytes in length, so no, it's reading the right amount of bytes.

Comment: Can you update the question with what your code looks like now?

Comment: If you are still using `ptr` in your call to `ReadFile` you need to dereference it with a `^` - otherwise you are reading onto the pointer itself, not the buffer it points to.

Comment: Ah, the `^` solved it. I've updated the question with my final code for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @JakeEvans But you really shouldn't use pointers if you don't need to. This answer gives a type-safe solution without all the risks involved with pointer operations. Missed dereferences, as in you most recent comment can be notoriously difficult to fix.... especially as your application gets larger and more complex.

Comment: Reading raw disc sectors into an array of `char` seems wrong to me. I suggest array of `byte` instead.